# Passing a Spinner value from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to get the value of the spinner set in the first fragment and pass the value along to fragment 2. At the moment I'm just trying to set one text field in fragment 2 to the spinner's value, but later on I'll need to somehow have the fragment 1 spinner value match a unit like meters, and then for fragment 2 to be able to take that unit and a user input to then convert it into a second chosen user input.

In fragment 2 I have just typed out some 'bad' psuedo code to showcase what I'm trying to do:

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_page1));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_page2));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new
                TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
        });



    }
```

Fragment 1

```
public class Page1Fragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1_fragment, container, false);


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);



        return view;

    }
```

Fragment 2

```
public class Page2Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2_fragment, container, false);
        fragment1Spinner = Page1Fragment.getSpinnerValue

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       text.setText(fragment1Spinner);

        return view;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onItemSelectedListener on your spinner to get the value selected in spinner. Store it in an variable and use setArguments and get arguments method of fragment to set and get the value..

Example:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        // this line will get you the selected item of the spinner
        String selectedValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
    {

    }
});
```

For setting the arguments to your fragment...considering you have a method in your fragment names newInstance. set this when navigating to second fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("selectedSpinnerItemKey", selectedSpinnerItemValue);

Fragment fragment = YourFragment.newInstance();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContent, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Now getting the arguments in second fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (getArguments() != null)
    {
        String itemFromFirstFragment = getArguments().getString("selectedSpinnerItemKey");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where the second method is meant to be placed

Comment: I've edit the answer please check and hope it solves your issue.